# Add rectangles over dates D3

Tags: javascript, csv, svg, d3.js, rect

I have the csv;

```
start_dt,end_dt
2012-08-01 00:00:00,2012-08-02 06:30:00
2012-09-02 13:00:00,2012-09-02 15:00:00
2012-09-12 00:00:00,2012-09-12 06:00:00
2012-11-06 05:00:00,2012-11-06 16:00:00
```

I require to add a transparent rectangle over each span (start_dt - end_dt) to a D3 chart which alrady contains a line path with datetime x-axis.

I get the data from the csv via;

```
d3.csv("{% static 'historicaldata/csv/bad_data.csv' %}", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.start_dt = parseDate(d.start_dt);
    d.end_dt = pareseDate(d.end_dt);
});
```

How do I create these rectangles in the context of time, relative to the line path that is already present, and add them to my svg container?

I have already defined dimensions;

```
height = 275 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

EDIT:

fiddle with js function concerned http://jsfiddle.net/3emn74yr/2/

Comment: make a fiddle then we could do for you.Okay

Comment: @saikiran the version i'm working on moight not work and you won't have access to the data. but i'll put some code up if you like. would you like the entire javascript or just the function in question?

Comment: behalf of this 
d3.csv("{% static 'historicaldata/csv/bad_data.csv' %}", function(error, data) {
//xxxxx
}


declare one variable as data, and initialize it with your data.

Comment: sorry, i'm not really sure i follow you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use your x-scale to set the x-coordinate of the rects based on the start date, and set the width to be the difference in the x-scaled values of the end and start dates.

For example, if you want your rects to span the full height of your chart, you could do this:

```
svg.selectAll('.time-span-rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'time-span-rect')
    .attr('x', function(d) { return x(d.start_dt); })
    .attr('y', 0)
    .attr('width', function(d) { return x(d.end_dt) - x(d.start_dt); })
    .attr('height', height);
```

Then if you  want them to be transparent, you can either set

```
.attr('fill', 'transparent')
```

or target the class in your css:

```
.time-span-rect {
  fill: transparent;
}
```

[**HERE**](http://plnkr.co/edit/KWlQqBMxeja6j5r97mAB?p=preview) is an example you can look at using your time-span data and a random line graph. I've made the x-scale a [`d3.time.scale`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#scale) rather than a linear scale, since it makes working with the axes quite a bit simpler. You might want to consider doing the same. Also, I've made the rects' fill `cyan` just so they show up. Simply change the css fill to `transparent`. Hope that helps.

Comment: In the middle of implementing to fit in with my script but this looka good. thanks @jshanley

Comment: @jshanleyi'm sure your answer will work. i'm just having a few problems in getting it to. i pull data from two csvs - one for the line and one for the rectangles. the line draws fine. i just can't get the rectangles to draw. would you mind taking a look at a new fiddle or plunker if i were to put one up for me?

Comment: there you go. my problem function and style sheet are up there. If you want anything more then let me know

Comment: got it to work! it was a wrongly spelt alret that was breaking it